# Django TestCase doesn't rollback DB when atomic transaction fails

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, transactions, atomic

I need help with writing a unit test that tests atomic transactions

I'm simply writing code that transfers money from a sender account to a receiver account by decreasing the amount of money from the sender and adding it to the receiver. I want to run the code in an atomic transaction because I want it to either all succeed or all fail. I want to write a test case that verifies that if the deposit function fails, the withdrawal should also be rolled back and the balance of the sender should stay the same.
The problem is that the test case fails as it shows that the sender balance is decreased although it should be rolled back.
Any help?

here's a small snippet of what I want to achieve

```
import pytest
from cards.models import Card, Account
from unittest.mock import patch

def perform_atomic(txn, sender_account, receiver_account, amount):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            sender_account.balance -= 1000
            sender_account.save()
            receiver_account.deposit(amount)
    except Exception as error:
        txn.status = Transaction.TRANSACTION_STATUS_FAILED
        txn.save()
        logger.error(f"Failed Action. Reason[{error}]", exc_info=True)
        raise error  

# Test case
@patch.object(Account, "deposit")
def test_atomicity_when_deposit_fails(self, deposit_mock):
    deposit_mock.side_effect = ValidationError("deposit failed")
    self.sender_account.balance = 300.0
    self.sender_account.save()

    # Balance before attempting to transfer
    before_sender_balance = self.sender_account.balance
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError, match="deposit failed"):
        perform_atomic(self.transaction, self.sender_account, self.receiver_account, self.amount)

    self.sender_account.refresh_from_db()

    # Balance after attempting to transfer
    after_sender_balance = self.sender_account.balance.amount
    
    # assert that the sender balanc didn't change
    assert before_sender_balance == after_sender_balance
```

I tried using **TransactionTestCase** instead of **TestCase** but to no avail. I use VS code to debug the code and when I debug the code line by line the testcase succeeds. I don't know why this weird behaviour happens